# What is the difference between virtual batch normalization and batch normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, batch-normalization

I know what batch normalization is but I don't quite get how to do virtual batch normalization. How do you choose the reference sample?

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in that each batch x of the former is normalized based on the statistics collected on a reference batch of examples that are chosen once and fixed at the start of training, but in the latter the batch is normalized with in itself. And the latter suffers from the interdependence of the samples inside each minibatch.

I think it is just like how you choose the query point in [locally weighted linear regression](http://vilkeliskis.com/articles/machine-learning-locally-weighted-linear-regression). You just choose one according to your experience.

In fact, the [demo in the official repository](https://github.com/openai/improved-gan/blob/master/imagenet/model.py) just uses the first batch when they start training.

```
if not hasattr(self, name):
    vbn = VBN_cls(tensor, name, half=half)
    setattr(self, name, vbn)
    return vbn.reference_output
```

You can choose any batch as the reference batch if it stays the same through the whole training.